# Instagram API: getting the user id of all the users who have liked a post

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy, instagram

How can I get all the users who have liked an image? I see that in `page_info` of a specific photo with 76 likes, there's `u'end_cursor': None` which I couldn't use in order to get the rest of the likes. Also as seen in this `JSON` only 10 of user's ID are shown.

```
                  u'page_info': {u'end_cursor': None,
                                 u'has_next_page': False,
                                 u'has_previous_page': False,
                                 u'start_cursor': None}},
```

http://pastebin.com/AZUQBvrF
I had a similar problem with traversing to other pages of an Instagram user which I solved using the following code. However, I am unsure how to handle this when `end_cursor=None`? Please suggest solution and guidance.

```
 99             while data["user"]["media"]["page_info"]["has_next_page"]:
100                 end_cursors.append(data["user"]["media"]["page_info"]["end_cursor"])
101                 data = json.loads(requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/ducks_love_sun/?__a=1&max_id={}'.format(end_cursors[-1])).text)
102                 #pprint(data)
103                 
104                 for i in range(len(json_response["user"]["media"]["nodes"])):
105                     count = count + 1
106                     print json_response["user"]["media"]["nodes"][i]["likes"]["count"], count
```

In a single image we see this:

```
 u'likes': {u'count': 76,
                       u'nodes': [{u'user':
```

but there's only 10 nodes shown in the json!

Feel free to look at this for an example:
https://www.instagram.com/p/BRG1WiEA1yM/?__a=1

I tried the followed but still get the content of 10 nodes:

```
pprint(img_response["media"]["likes"].items())
```

result is shown here: http://pastebin.com/7rPLqnUS

**UPDATE: as you see in this pastebin, the json of a photo with many comments has end_cursor and I can use that to traverse all of the comments:

```
http://pastebin.com/wbeZAt8y
```

While there's no cursor for likes seemingly!

Comment: how you can get more comments by using end_cursor? I am adding "&max_id=endCursorVALUE" at the end of link but still it returns same json which it resturn in this link https://www.instagram.com/p/BYAqj37lPCz/?__a=1

Comment: Hi Mona,
I am trying to pull the likes information of a media using Instagram API.
When I hit the API am just getting my username and ID if I like my media. If not it is giving an empty data set could you please let me know if am missing anything.

Thanks,
Ankush Reddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That reverse endpoint will not return more than 10 instagram photo liked user id.

So you can use Instagram official API endpoint to get all liked user id https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/#get_media_likes

Comment: This API no longer exists